# What function is this?

Tags: functions

I'm trying to find a function. And although it seems to be very simple at first I can't figure it out. Maybe I just need some sleep, and maybe someone could help me out.

```
given an Integer x between 0 and 100:
if x is between 0-10 then f(x)=0
if x is between 11-20 then f(x)=11
if x is between 21-30 then f(x)=21
if x is between 31-40 then f(x)=31
...
if x is between 91-100 f(x)=91
```

I'm trying to find the simplest f possible.

The best I could do is:

```
f(x) = x / 10 * 10
```

But it's not right.

What function is f?

**EDIT**

I'm accepting @Didier's solution but I'm going with this one instead.

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
1+10\lfloor (x-1)/10 \rfloor & \mbox{if } x >10; \\ 
0 & \mbox{if } x \leq 10 \end{cases}$$

Comment: What language are you using? As I mentioned in comments to the answers, your problem becomes slightly easier if your environment treats `0` and `1` as Booleans...

Comment: I'm on Javascript

Comment: JS, huh? Well then: `(x < 11 ? 0 : (10*Math.floor((x-1)/10)+1))` ...

Comment: P.S. [tag:generating-functions] is for something quite different...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $H$ denote the [Heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function), using the convention that $H(x)=1$ if $x\ge0$ and $H(x)=0$ if $x<0$. Then, for every $x$,
$$
f(x)=H(x-11)+10\,\sum\limits_{k=1}^9H(x-1-10\,k).
$$
An equivalent formulation, based on [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), is
$$
f(x)=[x\ge11]+10\,\sum\limits_{k=1}^9[x\ge1+10\,k].
$$
Still equivalently, but less rigorously,
$$
f(x)=[x\ge11]+10\,[x\ge11]+10\,[x\ge21]+10\,[x\ge31]+\cdots+10\,[x\ge91].
$$

Comment: I have no idea of what you mean. But it looks like cheating to me. A magical function that get's rid of the different range problem. You sure there's no simpler function?

Comment: If OP is working in a C-ish language, one could formally replace the unit step functions with Iverson brackets...

Comment: @eduardo: What's cheating here? Your function is piecewise-defined, and unit step functions are used for representing piecewise-defined functions among other things...

Comment: Sorry I was just checking. I'm not a pro mthematician like you guys. But I'm still trying to understand this function. The $\sum$ is puzzling me. I think I'll go with 2 separate functions, one for the first range and one for the second.

Comment: @eduardo: The $\sum$ means you can use a `for` loop or `while` loop, as the case may be...

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for mentioning Iverson brackets.

Answer (score 2):

In C notation,

```
(x > 10 ? 1 : 0)*((x-1)/10*10 +1)
```

Comment: Yup, the inline conditional would be best, but I'd have done `(x <= 10 ? 0 : 1 + (x-1)/10*10)` or something...

Comment: This is very useful, thanks for providing this, I'm accepting Didier's because it's more in line with my question about a single function to solve the case. Though your solution is better in pratical terms to me.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = 1+10\lfloor (x-1)/10 \rfloor$ works, except for the first range. Are you sure that $f(x)$ is not $1$ for $0 \le x \le 10$?

Comment: yes I'm sure. But thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

The function *would* be 
$$f(x)=10\left\lfloor\frac{x-1}{10}\right\rfloor+1$$
where $\lfloor \;\;\;\rfloor$ denotes the [floor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions), **except** that the definition for $0\leq x\leq 10$ does not match the pattern of the other parts of the definition - if you defined $f(x)=1$ for $1\leq x\leq 10$ and $f(0)=-9$, then the above function would be correct for all inputs.

Comment: This is exactly what is driving me crazy. The first range doesn't match. But the question is correct.

Comment: If you multiply $f(x)$ with $[x-11 \geq 0]$ where $[p]$ is an Iverson bracket, then his problem's solved.

Comment: I had to google about the Iverson bracket. But it seems good. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket